# Can Alfresco join a domain (or use cifs without typing passwords)?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, alfresco

I have a windows 2012 domain.
I am trying Alfresco 5.1 COMMUNITY that should be able to show windows servers a passwordless cifs share.
I first would like to ask if it is really possible.
Then I would like to ask how to do it because documentation is incongruent.

Official documentation talks only about Alfresco enterprise and it did not say if the community version has the same feature or how to configure it.
Wiki has pages to show how to do passwordless CIFS but all marked as obsolete or for very old versions.
Even if you try a configuration that should work you then discovery that it worked only for windows versions up to XP because then NTLM v2 standard blocks Alfresco as a "man in the middle".

Thanks,
Mario

Comment: What documentation did you try to follow? How far did that get you? Where did you get lost? What parts weren't clear?

Comment: Edited following your questions

Answer (score 0):

Alfresco does not support to join a domain. The way to go is to

- setup LDAP group and user sync against your AD
- and configure Alfresco additional for kerberos authentication

The Alfresco server will use keytabs to authenticate with SPN for cifs and http so already authenticated domain users will get access to alfresco cifs without password prompt.